# Wordpress wp-emoji-release.min.js error since version 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Since the latest upgrade of wordpress to version 4.2.2, I'm seeing an error in my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.className.indexOf is not a function
  g.observe.childList @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2:4
```

It seems it is an issue for all wordpress users, who upgraded to 4.2.2. I saw a solution with a plugin to disable emojis, but I don't want to install an additionnal plugin. Anyone knows a turnaround or solution for this ?

Comment: Check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2/185578#185578